# Google cloud image serving URL issue

Tags: image, url, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, serving

I don't know if anyone already ran into this.

We are using Google Cloud Storage to use user uploaded images from our app.

We generate the serving URL like this:

```
$imgURL = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($bucketPath . $fileName, array("size" => 0));
```

The URL is created fine with an =s0 argument at the end. We use this on-the-fly resizing argument for displaying different sized versions of the stored files.

**The problem is that the original URL doesn't show the correct image while the resized image displays fine.**

The strange thing is that it only happens occasionally - so not for every image...

One example

The original generated serving URL displaying the ***wrong*** image:
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/NOpTGAEefkDfPOFbqAzAVCT7TqVxvDxaMYVum1g9CA88jRYWCL61JtbTI8tHTO7ueZMp-L_lm8s-WLfCvC3JRm9e3Yrk4IFGZlfT=s0

The resized version of the URL displaying the ***correct*** image:
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/NOpTGAEefkDfPOFbqAzAVCT7TqVxvDxaMYVum1g9CA88jRYWCL61JtbTI8tHTO7ueZMp-L_lm8s-WLfCvC3JRm9e3Yrk4IFGZlfT=s100

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the images public? Maybe the image is being cached?

Comment: They are. The whole idea of generating the serving URL is to make it publicly accessible. The problem is that the two links should display the same image and they don't.

Comment: From inspecting your two links today, they appear to be the same; perhaps this was a temporary error?

Comment: I hope so. Even though it diturbs me a bit that I don't know why it happened...